# Android API 23 white status bar hides the view content

Tags: android

I want to change status bar color from transparent to white. It works on all APIs from 21 to 28 but not on API 23 :-)

I tried many different combinations of `systemUiVisibility` flags but the result is:

- either white Status bar with dark text and no layout content,
- or visible layout content and white status bar with white text (invisible status bar).

I was not able to achieve both visible white status bar and visible XML layout of my app.

```
fun Activity.setStatusBarColorLight(drawer: DrawerLayout? = null) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP_MR1)
    this.window?.apply {
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = 0
        clearFlags(FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION)
        clearFlags(FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        addFlags(FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS or FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN)
        val color = AttributeUtils.obtainStyledAttributeColor(context, R.attr.colorPrimary)
        statusBarColor = color
        drawer?.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color)
        if (UtilsKt.isColorLight(statusBarColor) && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {   
            decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR           
        }
    }
```

}

```
fun Activity.setTransparentStatusBar(colorId: Int = android.R.color.transparent, drawer: DrawerLayout? = null) {
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    this.window?.run {
        val color = context.resources.getColor(colorId, theme)
        decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
        addFlags(FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        statusBarColor = color
        drawer?.setStatusBarBackgroundColor(color)
    }
}
```

}

Unfortunately, it seems there are no good tutorials on how to use these `systemUiVisibility` and window flags and their combinations :-(

Comment: post a screenshot

Comment: I just see the status bar and no layouts in the main window. even if i turn on `show layout boundaries`. Layout itself is correct and works on other APIs